# Opening UIView programmatically iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to open a window every time a if state is correct.
The thing is that the code works if i use it on a button but not on load. The error 
code says that the view is not int the window hierarchy.

```
    info *vs = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"run"];
   [self presentViewController:vs animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: is `self` onscreen when this runs?

Comment: Also, the title is unclear. You're instantiating and presenting a UIViewController subclass but your title suggests it's a UIView. That's a mistake, right?

Comment: how can i check this ? but self is the current wievcontroller so it should be.and yes its a sub class

Comment: Perhaps best to show more context around the code (in which method is the code you presently show?) and also the specific console output

Comment: the code is in load function. i figure it out that i works in all the other functions

Comment: can i substitute SELF whit anything else ?

Comment: "load function" is ambiguous. It sounds like you have the code in too early a load method. Always best to show more code. Your solution below is not a recommended solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a non repeatable timer to load a function that opens the other view. Its a bit strange but it gets the job done.

Comment: without examples this should probably just be a comment.

Comment: Do they have to give examples in an answer to *their own* question? The original question isn't even clear enough to tell what they wanted help with in the first place so it's not like an example would help anyone figure anything out.